# Is it possible to run a full profile Java EE 6 application in Wildfly 15?

Tags: jakarta-ee, wildfly

Is it possible to run a Java EE6 application (needs full profile) in Wildfly 15?

We already searched a lot but could not find an answer.

Comment: Why did you not just try it and ask about the problems which popped up?

Comment: If it used only the standard and no jboss/wildfly specific bits, then possibly. But unlikely will work with zero changes

Answer (score 0):

I tried to migrate a big web app. from EAP 6(ee6) to EAP 7(ee7). It was not backward compatible, JBOSS library stack has new versions of APIs. Something was deprecated, other just stopped working. A code change and setting change was nedded to go fix it.